# Temporarily stopping K8s and Cassandra cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cassandra, cass-operator

I have created a `Cassandra` cluster on `Kubernetes` using `cass-operator` on `gcp`. It is for my personal experimentation. To avoid incurring cost, I want to stop the cluster when I am not using it and start it when I need it without losing data. Is there a way to do so? Would setting number of `size` to `0` in `example-cassdc-minimal.yaml` stop the compute resources without losing data? If I change the size to `3` again later, would the existing data be picked?

UPDATE
changing the size in `example-cass-dc-minimal.yaml` doesn't work as I get error `The CassandraDatacenter "dc1" is invalid: spec.size: Invalid value: 1: spec.size in body should be greater than or equal to 1`

Comment: I think decreasing replicas count will force operator to decommission nodes one by one and since atleast one node is required to maintain data, doing it 0  should not be allowed. This is my general observation, never worked with cass-operator.

Comment: https://community.datastax.com/questions/6257/cluster-shutdown-and-startup.html